# Elastic Search - force results to be distributed in a selected facet (attribute)

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way we can ask Elastic Search to distribute search results among a facet. For example if I have products in 10 categories, can I ask elastic to return one from each category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your category term aggregation, use a top_hits with a size of 1.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html